# Cofibrant objects are isomorphic to their cofibrant replacements

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

It is well-known that in a model category $M$ (assuming *functorial* factorizations as part of the axioms) we can replace every object with a cofibrant one, up to equivalence. Indeed, we can find a natural transformation $q \ \colon Q\Rightarrow \text{id}_M $ which is pointwise a trivial fibration and $QX$ is cofibrant for every $X$.

Suppose that $X$ is already cofibrant. In that case we can find $s_X \ \colon X\to QX$ s.t. $q_Xs_X=\text{id}_X$ by the RLP of the trivial fibration $q_X$ with respect to the cofibration $\emptyset\to X$. I'm trying to show that $s_X$ is an actual inverse (making $q_X$ an isomorphism), but I'm stuck with the proof that $s_Xq_X=\text{id}_{QX}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually not true.  For instance, in the typical examples where the functorial factorizations are constructed by a small object argument, the construction pays no regard to whether the map you started with was actually already a cofibration and will massively change your object in almost all cases.  For instance, for the usual model structure on topological spaces, $QX$ will take a space and "formally" turn it into a cell complex by repeatedly adjoining cells to solve every possible lifting problem with respect to the maps $S^{n-1}\to D^n$.  Unless $X$ is empty, this will give a space which is much bigger than $X$ itself (for instance, for every point of $X$, you will end up adjoining cells along the constant maps from each $S^{n-1}$ to that point infinitely many times!).

Comment: Yeah, typically both $Q$ and $R$ will massively enlarge your object $X$, without any regard for whether it was already (co)fibrant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm trying to prove a similar statement for bifibrant objects. I was wondering if a bifibrant object $X$ is (naturally) isomorphic to its cofibrant-fibrant replacement $QRX$, where $R$ is the fibrant replacement functor. I suspect the answer should be "no" as well. Furthermore, given that the cofibrant replacement $QX$ of a cofibrant object $X$ is not isomorphic to $X$ in general, is there any condition on the model structure on $M$ for this to be true? For instance, I suspect this is the case for $\mathbf{sSet}$ with the Quillen model structure.

Comment: Well, of course, if every object is cofibrant, you could choose to define $Q$ to just be the identity functor.  But if you are defining $Q$ as just a special case of the more general  cofibration-trivial fibration factorization functor, then $QX$ will be quite different from $X$ even for the Quillen model structure on simplicial sets.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I don't know of any particularly natural examples where $QX$ is always the same as $X$.